# Roots of derivative

Tags: calculus

> If $f'(x)$ has non-real roots does it mean that $f(x)$ also has non-real roots?

My attempt:
I thought no and tried to prove it by examples. For example, $f(x) = x^3 + x$ but it satisfies the above condition. However, I can't understand the relation between the roots of $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$. Has it got to do with mean value theorems?

Comment: Is $f'(x) = x^3 + x$ or $f(x) = x^3 + x$?

Comment: @an4s thanks I edited the question.

Comment: For a polynomial? If all the roots of a polynomial are real, then by Rolle's theorem, the derivative has roots in between them. The number of spaces in between roots (including those with multiplicity) equals the degree. This implies that the derivative has also only real roots, or no roots. Therefore, if the derivative has a non-real root, then the polynomial has a non-real root.

Comment: What is $f$, on what domain is it defined ? Is it any differentiable function, or a power series, or an analytic function ?

Comment: For polynomials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem

Comment: Here, F(x) =0 has two solutions x=0 and $x^2=-b/a$ F'(x)=0 has solution $x^2=-b/3a$ therefore $ b/a > 0$ implies both F(x) and F'(x) have non real roots . Does it mean that if F'(x) has non real roots then F(x) should also have non real roots? Here F(x) is ax^3 + bx

Comment: @AmitHegde Yes, for polynomials it is true in general. Proving the counterpositive is simpler, as I did above. Prove that if all the roots of a polynomial are real, then all the roots of the derivative are real too.

Answer (score 4):

Take $f(x)=(x-1)e^{ix}$

$f'(x)=(1-i(1+x))e^{ix}$

$f'$ has a non-real root, but $f$ has only a real root.

Obviously you can restrict the question somehow (polynomials, polynomials with real coefficients etc.).